when I doing a search delegate in flutter I got this

Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: No static method
'searchProducts' with matching arguments declared in class
'ProductService'.
Receiver: ProductService
Tried calling: searchProducts()
Found: searchProducts(String, List) => List)



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
